# What are must read chess books every chess player has to read to become an Expert Class?

Tags: tournament, books

I'm a Class B chess player. I would like to reach Expert Class one day. What are must read chess books. Please provide a list of books.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. This question is clearly about books, the other about general improvement. Only the context is the same not the question.

Comment: Capablanca said he never read a chess book until after he became World Champion!

Answer (score 1):

Some favorites:

- [Secrets of Modern Chess Strategy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1901983072)
- [My 60 Memorable Games](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/190638830X)
- [The Life and Games of Mikhail Tal](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857442024)
- [My System](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1880673851)
- [Fire on Board](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857441508)

These books are all famous **and** very good.

Books by Nunn, Aagaard, Dvoretzky or [Yusupov](http://www.qualitychess.co.uk/products/13/195/yusupov_complete_series_in_hardcover/) are recommended, though you have to be careful to find those suitable for your level.

The [Polgar trilogy](http://www.qualitychess.co.uk/products/13/238/judit_polgar_trilogy_in_hardcover/) is very good and there is an upcoming series by [Boris Gelfand](http://www.qualitychess.co.uk/products/2/247/positional_decision_making_in_chess_hardcover_by_boris_gelfand/). Two absolute top players, but nevertheless very accessible books.

Metachess: I really liked [The Seven Deadly Chess Sins](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1901983366) and [Move First, Think Later](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9056913980).

Still, although I always read a lot of books, I would maintain that playing a lot of tournament games against stronger players is far more important.

Comment: I'm convinced that chess books continue to improve every year.  If you want to read a great chess book you can almost close your eyes and point.  I personally wear out the Jeremysilman.com sites and the TWIC John Watson book review site because I do want to avoid the flops, and make sure to read books aimed at my rating level, but I'm sure that other book review sites would also do well.  I think you can only limit yourself by looking for some exclusive list of must-reads.